# how to switch two values in one button action ins swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I know this is very simple question to ask but anyhow I couldn't find any solution from my own. I have one "repeat_Check", if I press for first time I present one view and if I press same "repeat_Check" for second time I have to hide the view. Its work fine for first time but not working on second time

here my sample code

```
@IBAction func repeat_button(sender: AnyObject) {

    repeat_Check.selected = true
    Checked = true

    if Checked == true {
        self.excludeView.hidden = true
        self.view2.hidden = false

        self.view2.frame = view2Frame

        var buttonFrame = view3Frame
        buttonFrame.origin.y = (self.excludeView.frame.origin.y + self.view2Frame.origin.y)
        self.view3.frame = buttonFrame

        Checked = false

    }else if Checked == false {
        let buttonviewFrame = self.view2.frame

        self.view3.frame = buttonviewFrame

        Checked = true
    }

    Checked = false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you click on button you always make `Checked = true` ... so condition always true

rather set Checked = true in `viewDidload()` and than in button action

```
@IBAction func repeat_button(sender: AnyObject) {

   repeat_Check.selected = true

   if Checked == true {
      self.excludeView.hidden = true
      self.view2.hidden = false

      self.view2.frame = view2Frame

      var buttonFrame = view3Frame
      buttonFrame.origin.y = (self.excludeView.frame.origin.y + self.view2Frame.origin.y)
      self.view3.frame = buttonFrame

      Checked = false

   }else if Checked == false {
      let buttonviewFrame = self.view2.frame

      self.view3.frame = buttonviewFrame

      Checked = true
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank You i made small mistake in ViewDidLoad i checked False